# Using NSUserDefaults for storing UISwitch state

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I am trying to persist the `UISwitch` state in my settings view of my application. Basically it is a `UITableView` and contains a few switches to get the user preferences. The below code explains how the switches are constructed (only one switch construct is given below, others are also constructed the sameway).

```
if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:SomeIdentifierB] autorelease];
            if (syncStartupSwitch) {
                syncSwitch.on = YES;
            }else {
                syncSwitch.on = NO;
            }

            [syncSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(syncAtStartup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


            NSLog(@"Why is this not working%@",(syncSwitch.on ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
                [cell.contentView addSubview:syncSwitch];
            cell.accessoryView = syncSwitch;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                //cell.reuseIdentifier  = @"Cell1";
        }
        cell.textLabel.text =cellValue;
        return cell;
    }
```

Now, I would like to store the state of the Switches using NSUserDefaults. So in my selector method implementation, I defined the NSUserDefaults like this:

```
-(void) syncAtStartup:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isOn]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        NSLog(@"%@",(syncStartupSwitch ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

    }else {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];
            //syncStartupSwitch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];

    }
}
```

Finally, in my viewDidLoad I wrote this line of code:

```
syncStartupSwitch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];
```

I am sure there is some missing logic to my implementation. Can somebody point out the flaw and correct me?

**UPDATE:** 
I took the suggestion from @jfalexvijay and used the below code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];
BOOL syncStartupSwitch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];
```

When I look into the Preferences folder, I see the plist getting created with the BOOL value in it. I then try to set the UISwitch state in cellForRowAtIndexPath method like this:

```
syncSwitch.on = syncStartupSwitch;
```

I also have this line of code in ApplicationWillTerminate and in the selector itself

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Still, after restarting the application on the simulator or device, the switch state is not restored...

What is my mistake in the above code?

Cheers,

iSee

Comment: You should not use "boolForKey" to get the value, if you use "setObject"; you should use valueForKey;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following code;

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];
BOOL test = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];
```

if you use following code, it will return YES;

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];
BOOL test = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];
```

Just test above code;

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. The above code is working fine. I can see the plist file getting updated with the BOOL but I am still unable to retrieve the BOOL and set the UISwitch accordingly....

Comment: I have tested with following sample; if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SyncAtStartup"]) syncSwitch.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SyncAtStartup"]; else //show alert. it is working fine

Comment: My bad I was going wrong in assigning the BOOL value to the UISwitch... Thanks I consider this as the best answer that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using setObject:forKey: try using setBool:forKey:.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"SyncAtStartup"];
```

Comment: Except you want "YES", not "TRUE".

Comment: YES and @"YES" are definitely not same things.

Comment: There is not much practical difference between YES/NO and TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: Somehow it is still not restoring the state after the application restarts :(

Comment: Instead of using if-else you can directly use syncSwitch.on as the parameter value of setBool. Have you checked that the value of syncSwitch.on is changing properly?

Comment: Ensure that `NSUserDefaults` is being sent a `synchronize` message, otherwise the change may not reflect immediately.